# Finding theme files of Magento

Tags: zend-framework, mage, magento

I want to do some changes in magento theme actually product detail page, but I am unable to find that what theme it is. There are 4 directories where files can be.

In app/design there are 2 directories, default and base and then further more
  And same is hierarchy in skin folder

So is there some place where I can see that which files are being used or is there some variables or functions in magento that I can use to check that from where it is getting file.  I don't know much about magento and zend framework.  I tried to echo some content in product_controller but it seems that I am not printing output in write file. So what can be the way for me to know that where is the file of product detail page view where I can add a form and some link, is there any sort of custom HTML in magento that I can add in product detail page? I actually want to have a form in it that will take it to anohter page that I will create in magento and that page will use some data from form. Or if there is some extension for it?

Please tell if you know any thing about it , that is really appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find out where your themes set from

- System > Configuration > Design
- System > Design
- turn on template hints from System > Configuration > Developer

or you can add `print_r(get_included_files());` to the end of index.php to see what files are actually used in current php page

Comment: I used the way of get_included_files to print all files and found related files

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which is set from following place

1. System > Configuration > Design
2. System > Design

here you can see the name of theme who layout,templates and skin is used 
then u can explore the folder having the same name as files from that folder are in use.